# Should you modify Zurbs SASS version of its Foundation framework?

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

We're using the SASS version of Foundation 4.

A co-worker is saying you shouldn't modify the sass files in case you want to update it in the future; which is a good point.

I think it's necessary to modify the files in order to make proper use of the existing mixins and nesting.

I'm hoping someone with more experience could shed some light on the proper way to use the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For development I would definitely suggest not touching the core files as your co-worker pointed out.

Since you are using SCSS, you can easily include the core files into your own version of them (which add/overwrite rules).

**Example:** `/scss/custom/components/_my_alert-boxes.scss`

```
@import("/scss/foundation/components/_alertboxes.scss") // Foundation core

$alert-border-style: dashed;

@mixin alert-close {
  //Override default mixin.
}
```

Then once you are ready for production you'd want to go back and remove all the unused rules, minify code, and all that good stuff.